# Batch file - reading csv value and change value

Tags: batch-file

I have an very large csv file with x,y,z data. What I am looking to do is write a batch file that pull all the values from column y and change the values negative (they are all positive currently). I have not had any luck so far with this. If there is someone out there that can help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it. I am fairly new to writing batch files and have not figured this one out. Again any help is very much appreciated.

I have tried

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

for /f "tokens=2 delim=," %%A in ("Book1.csv") do(
    echo "%%A"* -1 >>testfile.csv)
```

I am not getting the column values. I get csv with %a in one column

The csv file I have looks something like this...

```
45.123,78.564,123
44.654,77.256,23
44.789,74.123,78
```

I am attempting to change the y values so they are negative...

```
45.123,-78.564,123
44.654,-77.256,23
44.789,-74.123,78
```

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: This is not a code writing service. We're more than happy to try and help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. When you've done so and run into difficulty, you can explain what you're trying to do and the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. You'll find your experiences at this site will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], before you start posting here.

Comment: when you say replace column y with negative values, what do you mean? replace the actual value with a static value, or just substract from the currebt value. Can you post sample input data as well as expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem that you really want to change any values, you just want to display them as negative values, Copy the below ad give it a try.:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%i in (book1.csv) do (
    echo %%i,-%%j,%%k
) >> testfile.csv
```

Comment: Would this not be better? `@(For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=," %%A In ("Book1.csv") Do @Echo %%A,-%%B)>"testfile.csv"`

Comment: @Compo why not post an answer then?

Comment: If you're satisfied with what you've written then I'm happy to leave it here for @Chigago to improve things outside of your response.

Comment: @Compo Sometimes I help users to understand the layout. My way, should OP decide to change another colum value to negative, he can simply do so. With your code, he needs to change tokens in order to achieve. Sometimes we give users a simple solution in order to help them learn, not the more complex solutions to just make it work. Again, you are most welcome to post an answer.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard thank you for the help. That worked! I was curious do you know if it is possible to update the file you are reading with the updated value?  i.e to keep test.csv as the output but with column y values negative

Comment: @Chicago simple answer, no. You can however write everything to the temp file, then rename the original file (or delete) then simply rename the temp file to the old file name, which will make it look like you wrote to the original.